# SwiftUI - Animate resize of a view frame

Tags: animation, view, size, swiftui

How do you animate the size of a view, such that the view may grow or shrink using the frame height?
I need to transition between two known dimensions.

Comment: How did you try it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you need but here is a very basic example with a `Rectangle` that gets scaled when you tap the `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animate = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.animate.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Animate")
            })
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: self.animate ? 100 : 150, height: self.animate ? 60 : 90)
        }
    }
}
```

Please add some code to your next question or edit the question so people can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 12):

Since  `withAnimation { }`  animate everything related to State changes inside the closure , we can use `.animation()` modifier to animate specific one.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animate = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                    self.animate.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Animate")
            })
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: animate ? 100 : 150, height: animate ? 60 : 90)
                .animation(.default, value: animate) //you can change the animation you need 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The .animation(_ animation: Animation) modifier is deprecated. The right way to use that method is by also passing the value parameter. Eg.: .animation(.default, value: animate)